How to generate the seed job config from the existing jobs?
I'm working on making our jenkins infrastructure more resilient.  I've migrated most of our stuff to pipelines, and our jenkins server is deployed by helm/k8s, so they're both under source control.  The last bit I need to backup is the job definitions themselves.  From what I've read, I should use the JobDSL plugin and a seed job for this.  My question is: "Is there a simple way to generate the seed job config from the existing jobs?"
I'm managing 50-100 jenkins jobs, and writing individual seed job configs for each of them would be time consuming.  I'm hoping there's some kind of tool that can look at the existing jobs and generate the configs.

Creating DSL Scripts for Each Job
Yes, creating DSL scripts for each job can be time-consuming but beneficial in the long run. Here’s a more detailed breakdown:
Automated Way

You can use the XML Job to Job DSL plugin. However, as you mentioned, it might not work perfectly for all configurations. This plugin attempts to convert existing job configurations into Job DSL scripts, which can save time but may require some manual adjustments.

Manual Way
Job DSL API Viewer

Use the Job DSL API Viewer to manually create DSL scripts for your jobs. This tool provides a comprehensive reference for all the DSL commands and their syntax.

Inspect Element and XML Config

You can inspect the job configuration page in your browser and view the XML configuration of the job. This can help you understand the structure and settings of the job, which you can then replicate in your DSL scripts.


By combining these methods, you can efficiently convert your existing Jenkins jobs into DSL scripts, making your job configurations version-controlled and reproducible. If you need further assistance with any specific part of this process, feel free to ask!
